# How to upgrade Eclipse birt from 3.7.1 to 4.4.2 on tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, birt

I am currently running the birt version `3.7.1` in tomcat and that is working fine. Now i want to upgrade the birt into `4.4.2` on tomcat. The jars required for the previous version of birt is placed in the path `Tomcat\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\platform`. But for up gradation the documentations for birt 4.4.2 tells that to find the  `WebViewerExample` directory from the `birt-runtime-4_2_2` and to put it in the webapps directory of Tomcat. But this is not working. Also what i would do with the old plugins which present in the platform directory.

Comment: Did you face any problem after upgrading BIRT..?? I mean..did the older version report design successfully run on new version ?

Comment: Yes successfully running. But some ParameterValidationException were there, which solved after changing the parameter datatype that is  passing from ReportServlet  java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download OSGI run time `birt-runtime-osgi-4_4_2-20150217.zip`and extract it. Open the `ReportEngine` folder. Copy the plugins and configuration folder and put it in the tomcat directory  `Tomcat\webapps\yourapplication\WEB-INF\platform` and replace the existing one. Now copy the jars inside the `lib` folder in to the tomcat directory `Tomcat\webapps\yourapplication\WEB-INF\lib` and replace the existing one. Some times you are using some `ReportServlet` java class. So you also modify java code there to make available new rendering options like `xlsx`.